# Adverb modifying adjective

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

> There are **too many good** people to talk to.

> There are **too many same** cars as yours.

I couldn’t understand what the difference between two structure. In the first sentence I can use “too many” before “good” but someone told me to use “same” after “car” . Why we can’t use it before “same”? Is the second sentence wrong or should I say;

> There are too many cars same as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it works depends on the context.

> There are too many **good people** to talk to.

is ok because "good people" is a valid item. However,

> There are too many **same cars** as yours.

is not valid, because there is no such thing as "same cars". So you might say:

> There are too many **cars** (that are the) same as yours.

"cars" is fine. "same" is ok now because you moved it to a separate clause.